# Ubuntu 15.04 not shutting down on Acer Aspire E1-510

Tags: shutdown

Ubuntu is not shutting down on my acer aspire E1-510 laptop.
The related questions have not fixed this problem. Hope someone could help to raise this issue as a bug.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Other weird things that happen during use or shutdowb? Maybe update to 15.10

Comment: Im not getting any errors. After shutdown, screen freezes to ubuntu logo without turning off. Same problem exists in Kali linux also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Shut Down button, try

```
shutdown -h now
```

and see if it does anything different. The -h option *halts* the system after closing everything else out.